# Images not showing up in IE 8

Tags: html, css

In Internet explorer 8 ,the background image is not showing up for my footer.  I can't even find the reason because there is no Firebug or inspect element for IE.
Anyone who can tell me what could be the reason?  Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Wrong. IE8 has dev tools (press F12).

Comment: Please don't tag [html5][css3] if you're **not** using HTML5 or CSS3.

Comment: Also if you want to remove the link to your site, you should at least put the relevant code here so your question doesn't look meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the CSS shortcut for background, I find that specifying a colour as the first argument delivers the best results.

In your case:

```
background: transparent url(images/nav_bg1.jpg) repeat left top;
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1) "Use background-image instead of just background.  When I monkeyed with the html on your site, I got that to work for IE8."  That's what I said in my original post, but actually, what happened was that IE kindly inserted the quotes for me when I edited the style, which is what made it work.

2) I don't have IE 8 either, but I do have IE 9.  When you press F12, it brings up a debug window similar to Chrome or FireFox, and you can switch the compatibility mode to IE 8 there.

Edited to fix #1 above.

Answer (score 0):

```
background:url(images/nav_bg1.jpg)repeat left top;
```

images/nav_bg1.jpg should be in quotes.

EDIT:

testing in IE8 this worked.

```
body {background-image:url(images/nav_bg1.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat;
background-position:left top;
```

this didn't:

```
background:url(images/nav_bg1.jpg)repeat left top;
```

Comment: why it is showing in IE 9 then?

Comment: @user1115580 just because one browser handles ambiguous code in the way you'd hope, doesn't mean that other (particularly older) browsers will do the same.

Comment: Since when were the quotes necessary? If anything, there should be a space between `url()` and `repeat`. @SimonMayer `url(images/nav_bg1.jpg)` is completely unambiguous and valid CSS.

Comment: I just tested it in 8. It doesn't need quotes. My mistake.

Comment: I just tested it in 8 with no space before repeat and it breaks. Try adding a space. 

    background:url(images/nav_bg1.jpg) repeat left top;

Comment: agreed @BoltClock. No quotes has been my preference for many depressing years of building sites being rendered on IE6 upwards :/

Comment: @Isaac Fife: It should behave the same in any browser. It's actually incorrect to leave out the space... it's part of the grammar for many shorthand properties.

Comment: @BoltClock I believe you. I should have tested it with and without the space before I suggested either. It didn't work in IE8 for me with or without the space - The code in my edit works however.

Answer (score 0):

You are using background image png /24.IE has issues with it,Try using png/16..